# Plain TeX: Line up some text boxes

Tags: plain-tex

Forgive me for asking what is probably a trivial question. I'm working through the books but always seem to be confused when I sit down at the computer.

- I'm using **plain TeX**.
- I have three multiple-paragraph chunks-of-text.
- I want to line them up together so they spread horizontally across the page.

In other words, I want to do this:

```
This is a               This is another                 Hey look! A third
sentence.               nice sentence.                  sentence or two

                        Whoa, another paragraph!
```

It seems to me I want three `vbox`es with `\hfill` between them. I am not comprehending what additional steps I'm missing.

I assume that a solution would generalize to more boxes and not be dependent on the tabular formatting mechanism. I think this is probably a very simple problem I have greatly overthought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to set the `\hsize` of your vertical boxes, and as you want to align the baseline of the first line in the vertical boxes you want `\vtop`. Probably you need to give TeX some 'room to manoeuvre' in terms of the narrow boxes, so I'd use `\sloppy` or similar (from LaTeX). You also probably want no `\parindent` but do seem to want a `\parskip`. That leads to something like

```
\long\def\parbox#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \hsize0.2\hsize % Pick your size here
    \parindent0pt %
    \parskip\baselineskip
    \sloppy
    #1\par
  }%
}
\def\sloppy{%
  \tolerance 9999 %
  \emergencystretch 3em %
  \hfuzz 0.5pt %
  \vfuzz \hfuzz
}
\noindent
\parbox{This is a sentence}\hfil
\parbox{This is another nice sentence.\par  Whoa, another paragraph!}\hfil
\parbox{ Hey look! A third sentence or two}
\bye
```

One could of course set things up to have a 'spread these evenly' mechanism for an arbitrary number of boxes if you wanted, but that looks like more work than it's worth (particularly for a plain TeX context where the mark-up usually hides very little). I've hard-coded the width here, but in a real case I guess you'd perhaps make that a second argument.

Comment: Imho "sloppy" should be renamed to "abomination"

Comment: @morbusg There are various approaches here (I note egreg's used `\raggedright`): you do have to have some give somewhere for a narrow column. I've just picked one I could easily copy-paste :-)

Answer (score 9):

You may want to use `\halign`:

```
\long\def\vtopragged#1#2{\vtop{\hsize=#1 \raggedright #2}}

\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\tabskip=0pt
\halign to\hsize{%
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{\parskip=\baselineskip #}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt \cr
  This is a sentence.&
  This is another nice sentence.

  Whoa, another paragraph!&
  Hey, look! A third sentence or two.

  This one without a blank line between paragraphs.\cr
}
\endgroup
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use \valign:

```
\valign{%
    \vtop{%
    \hsize50mm
    \raggedright\parindent0pt\tolerance9999
    #
    }
\cr
    This is a sentence.\cr
    This is another\hfil\break nice sentence.\hfil\break

    Whoa, another paragraph!\cr
    Hey, look! A third\hfil\break sentence or two.\cr
}
\bye
```