# Mixing text and image in Optex

Tags: graphics, plain-tex, optex

I've tried to mix text and images in Optex, but the solution is far from perfect. It throws an error -- `Missing } inserted`. Besides, I'm quite unsure about whether the use of `\valign` and `\vtop` (unabashedly copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249520/plain-tex-line-up-some-text-boxes)) is the best option in this case.

[image]

```
\putpic 10cm -4.2cm 6cm \nospec {S10.jpg}

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=0  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget pretium urna, id congue tortor. Praesent sit amet malesuada est. Curabitur ut euismod libero. Morbi quis turpis eget tortor faucibus accumsan sed non dolor. Sed eu enim gravida, maximus dui a, ornare leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent scelerisque lectus metus, tempus maximus elit auctor vel. Ut tincidunt quam quis scelerisque venenatis. Suspendisse non vulputate sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Curabitur odio magna, venenatis vitae hendrerit eu, laoreet quis sem.

\puttext 9.9cm -1.5\baselineskip{
\valign{%
    \vtop{%
    \hsize60mm
    \raggedright\parindent0pt\tolerance9999
    #
    }
\cr
    \caption/f A colorful bird bathing in the rain.\cr}
}

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=-2
Cras urna ante, dictum vitae convallis eu, imperdiet pellentesque enim. Mauris lectus elit, dapibus ut augue nec, consectetur interdum justo. Proin sed auctor tellus. Proin in mauris nulla. Praesent tempor lectus nisi, at feugiat lectus dapibus vitae. Donec aliquam eu mi ut consectetur. Proin id consectetur lacus, quis condimentum diam. 


\bye
```

Comment: @wipet will help soon! :)

Comment: @JamesT, I'm sure he will, although I think the matter is more akin to a plain text issue than a specific optex issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the `\vadjust` is not needed here, you want to put only `\vtop` at desired place.

The problem is at the end of the `\caption` text. It must be finalized by `\cskip` or `\vskip...` or `\_par` etc. But explicit `\_par` doesn't work in `\puttext` now (I'll remove this bug soon), so use `\cskip` as a `\caption` text separator.

```
%\putpic 10cm -4.2cm 6cm \nospec {S10.jpg} % I have no your picture of the bird.

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=0  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget pretium urna, id

\puttext 10cm -1\baselineskip{%
    \vtop{
    \hsize60mm
    \raggedright\parindent0pt\tolerance9999
    \caption/f A colorful bird bathing in the rain.
    \cskip}%
}

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=-2
Cras urna ante, dictum vitae convallis eu, imperdiet pellentesque enim. Mauris lectus elit,

\bye
```

Better solution is to use single `\puttext` with the picture and caption together. I created `\vtop` started by `\kern0pt` in order to set the y-position by the top of the picture (see 0pt in the `\puttext` parameter).

```
\puttext 10cm 0cm {\vtop{\kern0pt
   \hsize=6cm \picw=\hsize
   \inspic {example-image.pdf}  % use your bird here.
   \medskip
   \iindent=0pt  % we don't want to have caption narrower
   \caption/f A colorful bird bathing in the rain.
   \cskip
}}
\nobreak

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=0  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget pretium urna, id

\hangindent=-6.5cm \hangafter=-2
Cras urna ante, dictum vitae convallis eu, imperdiet pellentesque enim. Mauris lectus elit,

\bye
```

You can say `\let\_narrowlastlinecentered=\ignoreit` just before `\caption` if you don't want centered formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's much cleaner now.